# Gridsim: Extend functionality in network flow

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on gridsim project in Java eclipse. I have found a network flow program, which works only for one-to-one connection between the sender and receiver. If the same user (sender) wish to send a message to any other receiver, the program does not work. Similarly, if a receiver wish to send message to two sender users, it does not work. Here, I'm including all the java files for this work. In order to run the program, we need to include external .jar file path in the project. `The gridsim.jar` and `simjava2.jar` files can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/gridsim/

The following are the programs. The main program is `FlowNetEx01.java`

```
package network.flow.example01;

import gridsim.*;
import gridsim.net.*;
import gridsim.net.flow.*;
import java.util.*;

// Test Driver class for this example

public class FlowNetEx01
{
    // Creates main() to run this example
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Starting network example ...");
        try
        {
            int num_user = 4;   // number of grid users
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            boolean trace_flag = false;  // mean trace GridSim events

            System.out.println("Initializing GridSim package");

            // It is essential to set the network type before calling GridSim.init()
            GridSim.initNetworkType(GridSimTags.NET_FLOW_LEVEL);
            GridSim.init(num_user, calendar, trace_flag);

            // In this example, the topology is:
            // user(s) --10Mb/s-- r1 --1.5Mb/s-- r2 --10Mb/s-- GridResource(s)

            Router r1 = new FlowRouter("router1", trace_flag);   // router 1
            Router r2 = new FlowRouter("router2", trace_flag);   // router 2

            String sender1 = "user1";
            String receipient1 = "test1";
            String sender2 = "user2";
            String receipient2 = "test2";

            // these entities are the senders
            FlowNetUser user1 = new FlowNetUser(sender1, receipient2, 5.0);
            FlowNetUser user2 = new FlowNetUser(sender2, receipient1, 20.0);

            // these entities are the receipients
            FlowTest test1 = new FlowTest(receipient1, sender2);
            FlowTest test2 = new FlowTest(receipient2, sender1);

            // The schedulers are redundent and will be stripped out soon
            FIFOScheduler userSched1 = new FIFOScheduler("NetUserSched_0");
            r1.attachHost(user1, userSched1);

            FIFOScheduler userSched2 = new FIFOScheduler("NetUserSched_1");
            r1.attachHost(user2, userSched2);

            FIFOScheduler testSched1 = new FIFOScheduler("FlowTestSched_0");
            r2.attachHost(test1, testSched1);

            FIFOScheduler testSched2 = new FIFOScheduler("FlowTestSched_1");
            r2.attachHost(test2, testSched2);

            //////////////////////////////////////////
            // Second step: Creates a physical link
            double baud_rate = 1572864; // bits/sec (baud) [1.5Mb/s]
            double propDelay = 300;   // propagation delay in millisecond
            int mtu = Integer.MAX_VALUE;;     // max. transmission unit in byte

            Link link = new FlowLink("r1_r2_link", baud_rate, propDelay, mtu);
            FIFOScheduler r1Sched = new FIFOScheduler("r1_Sched");
            FIFOScheduler r2Sched = new FIFOScheduler("r2_Sched");

            r1.attachRouter(r2, link, r1Sched, r2Sched);

            //////////////////////////////////////////
            // Final step: Starts the simulation
            GridSim.startGridSimulation();

            System.out.println("\nFinish network example ...");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.print(e.toString());
            System.out.println("Unwanted errors happen");
        }
    }

} // end class
```

Program-2:

```
package network.flow.example01;

import gridsim.*;
import gridsim.net.*;
import gridsim.net.flow.*;
import eduni.simjava.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FlowNetUser extends GridSim
{
    private int myID_;          // my entity ID
    private String name_;       // my entity name
    private String destName_;   // destination name
    private int destID_;        // destination id
    private double wait_;       // Delay until I begin sending

    public static final int SEND_MSG = 1;    
    public static final int ACK_MSG = 2;

    public FlowNetUser(String name, String destName, Link link, double wait) throws Exception
    {
        super(name, link);

        // get this entity name from Sim_entity
        this.name_ = super.get_name();

        // get this entity ID from Sim_entity
        this.myID_ = super.get_id();

        // get the destination entity name
        this.destName_ = destName;

        // get the waiting time before sending
        this.wait_ = wait;
    }

    public FlowNetUser(String name, String destName, double wait) throws Exception
    {
        // 10,485,760 baud = 10Mb/s
        super(name, new FlowLink(name+"_link",10485760,450,Integer.MAX_VALUE));

        // get this entity name from Sim_entity
        this.name_ = super.get_name();

        // get this entity ID from Sim_entity
        this.myID_ = super.get_id();

        // get the destination entity name
        destName_ = destName;

        // get the waiting time before sending
        this.wait_ = wait;
    }

    public void body()
    {
        int packetSize = 524288000;   // packet size in bytes [5MB]
        //int packetSize = 52428800;   // packet size in bytes [50MB]
        //int packetSize = 524288000;   // packet size in bytes [500MB]
        //int packetSize = 5242880000;   // packet size in bytes [5000MB]
        int size = 3;           // number of packets sent
        int i = 0;

        // get the destination entity ID
        this.destID_ = GridSim.getEntityId(destName_);

        //super.sim_pause(this.wait_);
        this.gridSimHold(this.wait_);


        // sends messages over the other side of the link
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {

            String msg = "Message_" + i;
            IO_data data = new IO_data(msg, packetSize, destID_);
            System.out.println(name_ + ".body(): Sending " + msg +
                ", at time = " + GridSim.clock() );

            // sends through Output buffer of this entity
            super.send(super.output, GridSimTags.SCHEDULE_NOW,
                       GridSimTags.FLOW_SUBMIT, data);

            //super.sim_pause();
            super.sim_pause(10.0);
            //this.gridSimHold((Math.random()*10)+1.0);

        }

         // get the ack back
        Object obj = null;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            // waiting for incoming event in the Input buffer
            obj = super.receiveEventObject();
            System.out.println(name_ + ".body(): Receives Ack for " + obj);
        }         

        // Wait for other FlowNetUser instances to finish
        this.gridSimHold(1000.0);

        super.send(destID_, GridSimTags.SCHEDULE_NOW,
                   GridSimTags.END_OF_SIMULATION);

        // shut down I/O ports
        shutdownUserEntity();
        terminateIOEntities();

        System.out.println(this.name_ + ":%%%% Exiting body() at time " +
                           GridSim.clock() );
    }

} // end class
```

Program-3:

```
package network.flow.example01;

import java.util.*;
import gridsim.*;
import gridsim.net.*;
import gridsim.net.flow.*;
import gridsim.util.SimReport;
import eduni.simjava.*;

public class FlowTest extends GridSim
{
    private int myID_;          // my entity ID
    private String name_;       // my entity name
    private String destName_;   // destination name
    private int destID_;        // destination id
    private SimReport report_;  // logs every activity

     public FlowTest(String name, String destName, Link link) throws Exception
    {
        super(name, link);

        // get this entity name from Sim_entity
        this.name_ = super.get_name();

        // get this entity ID from Sim_entity
        this.myID_ = super.get_id();

        // get the destination entity name
        this.destName_ = destName;

        // logs every activity. It will automatically create name.csv file
        report_ = new SimReport(name);
        report_.write("Creates " + name);
    }

    public FlowTest(String name, String destName) throws Exception
    {
        // 10,485,760 baud = 10Mb/s
        super(name, new FlowLink(name+"_link",10485760,250,Integer.MAX_VALUE));

        // get this entity name from Sim_entity
        this.name_ = super.get_name();

        // get this entity ID from Sim_entity
        this.myID_ = super.get_id();

        // get the destination entity name
        this.destName_ = destName;

        // logs every activity. It will automatically create name.csv file
        report_ = new SimReport(name);
        report_.write("Creates " + name);
    }

    public void body()
    {
        // get the destination entity ID
        this.destID_ = GridSim.getEntityId(destName_);

        int packetSize = 1500;   // packet size in bytes
        Sim_event ev = new Sim_event();     // an event

        // a loop waiting for incoming events
        while ( Sim_system.running() )
        {
            // get the next event from the Input buffer
            super.sim_get_next(ev);

            // if an event denotes end of simulation
            if (ev.get_tag() == GridSimTags.END_OF_SIMULATION)
            {
                System.out.println();
                write(super.get_name() + ".body(): exiting ...");
                break;
            }

            // if an event denotes another event type
            else if (ev.get_tag() == GridSimTags.FLOW_SUBMIT)
            {
                System.out.println();
                write(super.get_name() + ".body(): receive " +
                      ev.get_data() + ", at time = " + GridSim.clock());

                // No need for an ack, it is handled in FlowBuffer now on our behalf
                // sends back an ack
                IO_data data = new IO_data(ev.get_data(), packetSize, destID_);
                write(name_ + ".body(): Sending back " +
                      ev.get_data() + ", at time = " + GridSim.clock() );

                // sends through Output buffer of this entity
                super.send(super.output, GridSimTags.SCHEDULE_NOW,
                        GridSimTags.FLOW_ACK, data);

            }

           else if (ev.get_tag() ==  GridSimTags.INFOPKT_SUBMIT)
            {
                processPingRequest(ev);                
            }
        }

        // shut down I/O ports
        shutdownUserEntity();
        terminateIOEntities();

        // don't forget to close the file
        if (report_ != null) {
            report_.finalWrite();
        }

        System.out.println(this.name_ + ":%%%% Exiting body() at time " +
                           GridSim.clock() );
    }

    private void processPingRequest(Sim_event ev)
    {
        InfoPacket pkt = (InfoPacket) ev.get_data();
        pkt.setTag(GridSimTags.INFOPKT_RETURN);
        pkt.setDestID( pkt.getSrcID() );

        // sends back to the sender
        super.send(super.output, GridSimTags.SCHEDULE_NOW,
                   GridSimTags.INFOPKT_RETURN,
                   new IO_data(pkt,pkt.getSize(),pkt.getSrcID()) );
    }

   private void write(String msg)
    {
        System.out.println(msg);
        if (report_ != null) {
            report_.write(msg);
        }        
    }

} // end class
```

After running these programs, someone can tell us how to extend the required functionality as I mentioned in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Personal experience ... GridSim5.2 potentially buggy.
The examples are dated written for version  < 4.0, demonstrating not very complex scenarios.

Using version 5.2. According to the API docs every simulation should have at least one TopRegionalRC. This appends a UniqueID to the filename and records the location of the file in two hashmaps one for filename and the other for fileattr. Now the event filename used for the lookup remains unchanged - the lookup fails - compares to the fileattrmap.name_. Consequently, the waiting for ack block is never executed when performing a addmaster operation.
Fix: Since the UniqueId is returned by the initial request to the CTLG this can be appended to the filename for the subsequent event requiring the lookup. Alternatively, add the filename to fileattrmap and the filename+uniqueid to fileattrmap, then test for both in the lookup.

Also, GridSimTags uses -1 to signal END_OF_SIMULATION, but this conflicts with Advanced Reservation (AR) block of tags. That also use negative numbers. GridSimTags has an optional routine to check for duplicates but its use is optional and does not apply to DataGridTags. I created a reversemap for ease of debugging adding validation to ensure no duplicates occur and deprecated the GridSimTags method.

I am now wrestling with the DataGrid user tasks that do not seem to create events, I am also concerned that the delay operations are not effective.